# API for creating blogs on Multisite?

Tags: multisite, api

Is there some API or plugin that allows for creation of sites on a multisite install? Jetpack doesn't seem to allow it, and the xml rpc doesn't seem to support multisite. Is there something I can use as a JSON API or some other sort of http call to do this?

Comment: There is nothing in core for this functionality, no. The only ways to create a new site are the wp-signup.php, for open systems, and the network admin add-new-site screen, for closed ones. There may be plugins to do this sort of thing.

Comment: `wpmu_create_blog()` appears to be the function you can call from within a WordPress plugin. http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/wpmu_create_blog

Comment: This is an event thrown when a blog was created, not a way to create it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating one myself. I'm not sure if the new wordpress rest API contains functionality that duplicates this so you may want to investigate that first.

https://github.com/remkade/multisite-json-api

Comment: Please extend the answer since link only answers are not recommended, thanks.